# How to remove a substring between two specific characters in Scala

Tags: regex, string, scala, list

I have this List in Scala:

```
List[String] = List([[aaa|bbb]], [[ccc|ddd]], [[ooo|sss]])
```

And I want to obtain the same List with the substrings between | and ] removed and | removed too.

So the result would be:

```
List[String] = List([[aaa]], [[ccc]], [[ooo]])
```

I tried something making a String with the List and using replaceAll, but I want to conserve the List.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple `\|.*?]]` regex to match these substrings you need to remove.

Here is a way to perform the replacement in Scala code:

```
val l = List[String]("[[aaa|bbb]]", "[[ccc|ddd]]", "[[ooo|sss]]")
println(l.map(x => x.replaceAll("""\|.*?(]])""", "$1")))
```

See the [Scala demo](http://ideone.com/dnNGkM)

I added a capturing group around `]]` and used a `$1` backreference in the replacement pattern to insert the `]]` back into the result.

**Details**:

- `\|` - a literal `|` pi[e symbol (since it is a special char outide of a character class, it must be escaped)
- `.*?` - any zero or more symbols other than line break symbols
- `(]])` - Group 1 capturing `]]` substring (note that `]` outside of a character class does not need escaping, it is just the opposite of the case with `|`).

Comment: You don't need a capture group if you `replaceAll("""\|[^\]]+""", "")`, and it's still accurate if the level of `[]` nesting changes.

Comment: @jwvh: I know I could replace with `]]`. It is just a way to show what regex can do.

Comment: Granted, but if the string is `"[aa|bb]"` or maybe `"[[[x|y]]]"` then your solution (with or without the capture group) won't balance each `[` with a closing `]`.

Comment: @jwvh: There is no need balancing, see the OP: the format is fixed, `[[` + some chars other than `|`, then `|`, then some chars up to the first `]]`. If balanced brackets had been mentioned, I would have never suggested a Java regex solution *unless* the recursion depth were just 1 or 2 levels.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple solution that should be quite good in performance:

```
val list = List("[[aaa|bbb]]", "[[ccc|ddd]]", "[[ooo|sss]]")
list.map(str => str.takeWhile(_ != '|') + "]]" )
```

It assumes that the format of the strings is:

- Two left square brackets `[` at the beginning,
- then the word we want to extract,
- and then a pipe `|`.

Comment: This answer may be too brief. In addition to providing an MCVE, can you explain your solution? From [*How do I write a good answer?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "…try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: Clean and efficient, but not the result that the OP has requested.

Comment: You are right, I misread the question, sorry about that. I have edited the response

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 3 characters between `|` and `}` with `]`.

regex is `"\\|(.{3})\\]"` (do not forget to escape `|` and `}`)

```
scala> val list = List("[[aaa|bbb]]", "[[ccc|ddd]]", "[[ooo|sss]]")
list: List[String] = List([[aaa|bbb]], [[ccc|ddd]], [[ooo|sss]])

scala> list.map(_.replaceAll("\\|(.{3})\\]", "]"))
res16: List[String] = List([[aaa]], [[ccc]], [[ooo]])
```